# json encode and decode array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing my project in codeigniter. My issues is i will store value for `'game_aspect_details'` in json format like

`"{"game_aspect_details":[{"aspect_id":"1"},{"aspect_id":"4"}]}"`

for this select query i will decode the json format and  check that value in foreach.

```
    $this->db->select('game_aspect_details');
    $this->db->from('share_reviews');
    $this->db->where('review_id',6);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    $test = $result[0]->game_aspect_details;
    $res = json_decode($test);
    $result_array = array();        
    foreach ($res as $row)
    {            
        $this->db->select('comments');
        $this->db->from('review_ratings');
        $this->db->where('game_aspect_id',$row->game_aspect_details); //here i need
        $query1 = $this->db->get();                            to check 1 and 4 
        $resultReviews['comments'] = $query1->result();
        $result_array[] = $resultReviews;

    }
    print_r($res);
    exit;
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i need to decode that json format and i have to get the value 1 and 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this do see what you are getting in the `$row` within the `foreach` by using the `print_r()`.

And I hope that you need to replace the below line

```
$this->db->where('game_aspect_id',$row->game_aspect_details);
```

With following line:

```
$this->db->where('game_aspect_id',$row['aspect_id']);
```

as `$row` is an array not an object.

**EDITED:**

```
foreach ($res as $rows)
{            
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {            
    ........
    $this->db->where('game_aspect_id',$row['aspect_id']); //here make change
    .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [aspect_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [aspect_id] => 4 ) )

Comment: when i print_r($row) inside foreach i can get like this

Comment: @sangee then use the code that is in the answer that will work for you sure.

Comment: that means u r telling me to use like this

Comment: @sangee yes, the edited code check that and use that.  at the place of dot dot use you code.

Comment: @sangee I have also mention the reason in the answer.

Comment: s its partially working that means its working checking the value for 1 not for 4

Comment: @sangee are you using the $i variable as I have mention in the edited post.

Comment: $i=0;  
  foreach ($res as $row)
  {   
   
   $this->db->select('comments');
   $this->db->from('review_ratings');
   $this->db->where('game_aspect_id',$row[$i]['aspect_id']);
   $this->db->where('review_id',6);
   $query1 = $this->db->get();
   $resultReviews['comments'] = $query1->result();
   //$result_array[] = $resultReviews;
   $i++;
    
  }
  print_r($resultReviews);
  exit;

Comment: @sangee got you exact problem and have edited the answer's edited part .use that, it will surly work for you.

Comment: @sangee nothing is wrong in that but your first foreach is giving the both the values in a multidimensional array. so you need to use another foreach.

Comment: {
   "data": {"comment":    [
      {"comments":       [
         {"comments": "she had no winners^$$$^no chance!"},
         {"comments": "super"}
      ]},
      {"comments": [{"comments": "supera"}]}
   ]}
}

Comment: {  "data": {"comment":    [
      {"comments":       [
         {"comments": "she had no winners^$$$^no chance!"},
         {"comments": "super"}
         {"comments": "supera"}]}
   ]}
}

Comment: i need to get like this in a single comments: i need to display all the comment

Comment: @sangee Is your query working fine as I have suggest you or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some things wrong, see the comments in this code:

```
...
//$test = $result[0]->game_aspect_details; // This does not work since $result is not decoded yet
$res = json_decode($result); // Changed to `$result` instead of `$test`
$res = $res->game_aspect_details; // Instead pick the `game_aspect_details` here, after the decode
$result_array = array();        
foreach ($res as $row)
{            
    $this->db->select('comments');
    $this->db->from('review_ratings');
    $this->db->where('game_aspect_id',$row['aspect_id']); // Changed to `aspect_id`
    $query1 = $this->db->get();
    $resultReviews['comments'] = $query1->result();
    $result_array[] = $resultReviews;
}
...
```